# Are there other European parties that officially have only one member, but get a large number of parliament seats?

Tags: parties, parliament, europe

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party_for_Freedom#Organisation_and_support):

> After the creation of the association, Wilders disabled new member registration, resulting in his remaining the sole member of the party. The party is considered unique in Dutch politics in that it does not organise public party conferences and does not have local departments, a youth wing, or a research institute.Instead, PVV supporters have the option of financially donating to the party or signing up as unaffiliated volunteers during elections. Candidates are mostly handpicked by Wilders who also writes the PVV's platform. Former PVV politician Hero Brinkman unsuccessfully tried to lobby for the party to adopt a conventional membership system and a youth wing. However, Wilders has defended the party's structure, stating that he does not want extremists to take over the PVV [...]

I know that Lukashenka's [party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belaya_Rus) in Belarus was in a somewhat similar position for quite a while, only being a fans association (that Lukashenka wasn't actually a member of), so e.g. the 2019 parliament [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Belarusian_parliamentary_election) was 60% comprised of "independents", but the latter recently formally converted to a party.

OĽaNO in Slovakia was somewhat more similar to the PVV perhaps, with membership being more or less decided by its leader (according to Wikipedia), but it had a greater than one, albeit still small number of members.

> OĽaNO lacks any internal democratic structures, and Matovič decides on the composition of the electoral list, admission of members and political nominations. [...] OĽaNO claimed to have 50 members as of 31 December 2021.

So, besides PVV, are there other parties in Europe like that, i.e. that have officially a single member, but hold a significant number of parliamentary seats?

Comment: N.B. OĽaNO apparently increased its membership from 4 to 50 in 2019, in response to a law that set a minimum of 45 https://domov.sme.sk/c/22249737/olano-meni-stanovy-a-pocet-clenov-podla-matovica-ostavaju-nestandardni.html

Comment: That is quite a legal loophole Wilders used: a party needs to be a registered association, an association needs to have at least two members, but they can be legal personalities.  One member is Geert Wilders, the other his personal foundation, of which Geert Wilders is the only director.

Comment: @ccprog: "me, myself and I" :-0

Comment: Hm. The CoE [Venice Commision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venice_Commission), in its _Guidelines on Political Party Regulation, Second Edition_ [CDL-AD(2020)032](https://www.venice.coe.int/webforms/documents/default.aspx?pdffile=CDL-AD(2020)032-e) para. 156 mentions "There even are political parties that are not membership-based, formally and/or in fact consisting only of a leader and possibly a few colleagues.", but the footnote **only** mentions the PVV.

Comment: So they can only fill 1 seat in parliament as the party only has one member?

Comment: @haxor789 In Germany, non party-members can be elected as part of the party's list. This is rare because party members (who make the list) tend to select each other but it would be possible. I suspect the Netherlands has a similar system.

Comment: @xyldke But do these seats then belong to the party and does party "discipline apply" and does that party get the cash for the votes or do they belong to the members? I guess I need to write a question about these :)

Comment: Reform UK (formerly the Brexit Party, not to be confused with UKIP) has an [unusual structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reform_UK#Funding_and_structure) with 3 members and no party democracy, although it doesn't have many seats (maybe in 2024 that will change). There are also people who've been elected to the presidency of countries without having any party or members of parliament.